# Associate session bean in application Context

Tags: java, cdi, weld, weld2

I have session id map and I want to get each session associated with session id.
BoundSessionContext is told to use but I could not figure put how to set map value to it. Is there any code sample or another way to achieve getting sessionContext.

I m using  wildFly-8.1.Final.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jboss.weld.context.bound.BoundSessionContext

Comment: Yep,i tried that, session bean is working but related beans in session bean not injected properly. i guess BoundSessionContext  is not bounded to session that i want to work in. i could not figure out what to pass in map that i used floowing statement sessionContext.associate(map);